# Part of the Mesh goes missing

Tags: animation, mesh, bones, blend-files

I was modifying some of the weight paint for a hand model that I was getting ready for some simple hand animation gestures and when I started doing some of the animations I saw that there was a piece of my mesh missing. How do I fix this? Do I have to start all over? pictures and file below.

[image]

File here:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5Q_BpDCNgg6cG9zM2UxeFlwcDQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Still need some help I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: I checked the weights and they're quite decent. It is really strange it deforms in the ugly way. I had similar problem with strange mesh deformations some time ago and had to build (retopologize) my model again from scratch to make everything work properly. Maybe it's some kind of a bug??

Comment: Thanks, Did not know what retopologize ment until I looked it up. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Imho weights are not that OK. there are many isolated vertices here and there that have weights and (always imho) they should have zero.

Answer (score 1):

I just post this to show some error in the weights. I downloaded your file and just reset the pose of all bones (ALT + R)

then selected bone.001:

[image]

this bone is not supposed to influence the hilighted area...

there are also many minor errors, maybe just 1 vertex here and there, quite subtle on various bones, but those also "move" your geometry in unexpected ways...